# "tagNameFormat" property is not applied in Maven Release plugin

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm using the "tagNameFormat" configuration property on the Maven Release plugin to only use the project version as the tag, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. When I run a mvn release:prepare the suggested tag is still in the form {artifactId}-{version}.

My config is as follows:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <tagBase>https://as3-commons.googlecode.com/svn/tags/parent-pom</tagBase>
    <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
    <goals>deploy</goals>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works for me with latest maven (3.0.4) and 2.2.2 of maven release plugin on a mercurial 
repository.

Pom snippet

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Log

```
D:\work\cloneProject>mvn release:prepare
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-app 1.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.2.2:prepare (default-cli) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Verifying that there are no local modifications...
[INFO]   ignoring changes on: pom.xml.next, release.properties, pom.xml.releaseB
ackup, pom.xml.backup, pom.xml.branch, pom.xml.tag
[INFO] EXECUTING: cmd.exe /X /C "hg status"
[INFO] [release.properties:unknown]
[INFO] Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
What is the release version for "my-app"? (com.mycompany.app:my-app) 1.1: :
What is SCM release tag or label for "my-app"? (com.mycompany.app:my-app) 1.1: :
```